# Child widget creation in ipywidgets produces an error using ViewList and create_child_view

Tags: javascript, python, backbone.js, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

### Summary

See the toy example Azure notebook [hosted at this link](https://notebooks.azure.com/rickteachey/projects/geoselector/html/broken_example_simple.ipynb). The notebook can be cloned and run, or downloaded and run locally, from there, but all of the code is also below for convenience.

When all the cells are run, the javascript console reports these errors (abbreviated) in the final cell, and the final expected line of output does not render:

```
Error: Could not create a view for model id 91700d0eb745433eaee98bca2d9f3fc8
    at promiseRejection (utils.js:119)
Error: Could not create view
    at promiseRejection (utils.js:119)
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Not sure where I am going wrong.

UPDATE:

As it currently exists, the code sends a string instance (rather than a `DOMWidgetModel` instance) to the `create_child_view` method. The string contains `"IPY_MODEL_"` appended by the model id. This seems like it might be the root of the problem. That string instance is being received by the client from the server side Backbone `children` model array items (`this.model.get('children')`).

I am wondering if the problem is related to the [de]serialization of  widgets discussed in the [low-level widget tutorial](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Low%20Level.html#Serialization-of-widget-attributes). But I'm not sure how to use that to fix this problem, since I need access to the sub widget model itself and not just an attribute. And I believe I am correctly passing the `**widgets.widget_serialization` as the tutorial specifies.

---

### Details

The notebook contains python and javascript code, and utilizes the [`ipywidgets`](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library, which relies heavily on Backbone. The back end code (python, cell #1) creates a `ipywidgets.DOMWidget` subclass widget, `Test` (a Backbone model mirrored in the front end). The front end code (javascript, cell #2) creates a `ipywidgets.DOMWidgetView` subclass, `TestView`, which is instantiated by the widget when it is rendered to the page.

The `Test` model widget has a `children` member made up of multiple "sub-widgets" (which are also models). These widgets are instances of the python class `Sub`. When a view of `Test` is rendered, I want to instantiate and render the views of the children widgets and attach them to the view of the parent `Test` widget (note: that final part hasn't been implemented yet below).

The problem is that when I try to follow the `ipywidgets` API to create children views, populating the `ViewList` array by instantiating the children views using the `create_child_view` method on each child model is not working.

The API for this kind of thing isn't particularly well documented, so I'm doing my best to follow various similar examples of how to instantiate sub-views using child models from within a parent view, such as the parent widgets [in `ipywidgets` itself](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/blob/1f93ad39802d3ee4a6b88bc13064f93f8f796374/packages/controls/src/widget_selectioncontainer.ts#L196-L210) and [in `ipyleaflet`](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/blob/b6d2c1573fbb00cd1511df26244e65d2159c11c0/js/src/layers/LayerGroup.js#L20-L40). But nothing I do seems to get the creation of children views working.

Note that I am able to render a view of each `Sub` widget *individually* without any problem. It is only when I try to use the `create_child_view` method to create a view from within the parent `Test` widget that we run into problems.

---

### Code

**Cell 1** (server side jupyter python kernel)

```py
import ipywidgets.widgets as widgets
from traitlets import Unicode, List, Instance
from IPython.display import display


class Sub(widgets.DOMWidget):
    """Widget intended to be part of the view of another widget."""
    _view_name = Unicode('SubView').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module = Unicode('test').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module_version = Unicode('0.1.0').tag(sync=True)


class Test(widgets.DOMWidget):
    """A parent widget intended to be made up of child widgets."""
    _view_name = Unicode('TestView').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module = Unicode('test').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module_version = Unicode('0.1.0').tag(sync=True)
    children = List(Instance(widgets.Widget)).tag(sync=True, 
                                        **widgets.widget_serialization)

    def __init__(self, subs):
        super().__init__()
        self.children = list(subs)
```

**Cell 2** (front end jupyter notebook code)

```
%%javascript

require.undef('test');

define('test', ["@jupyter-widgets/base"], function(widgets) {

    var SubView = widgets.DOMWidgetView.extend({

        initialize: function() {
            console.log('init SubView');
            SubView.__super__.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        },

        render: function() {
            this.el.textContent = "subview rendering";
        },

    });

    var TestView = widgets.DOMWidgetView.extend({

        initialize: function() {
            console.log('init TestView');
            TestView.__super__.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
            this.views = new widgets.ViewList(this.add_view, null, this);
            this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:children', function(model, value) {
                this.views.update(value);
            }, this);
            console.log('init TestView complete');
        },

        add_view: function (child_model) {
            // error occurs on this line:
            return this.create_child_view(child_model);
        },

        render: function() {
            this.views.update(this.model.get('children'));
            this.el.textContent = 'rendered test_view';
        },
    });

    return {
        SubView : SubView,
        TestView : TestView,
    };

});
```

**Cell 3** (python code for testing)

```py
models=[Sub() for _ in range(4)]
for m in models:
    # view each Sub object individually
    display(m)  # output: 'subview rendering'
t=Test(models)
t  # output: 'rendered test_view'  <-- broken; see console log
```

---

### Output

Current output:

```
subview rendering  

subview rendering  

subview rendering  

subview rendering
```

Expected output:

```
subview rendering  

subview rendering  

subview rendering  

subview rendering  

rendered test_view
```

More specific information about the actual project I am working on is at [this github issue](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2420#issuecomment-496681171) if anyone is interested.

Comment: Do you have any image, how the output should look like ?

Comment: @ASHu2 I added the expected output (and some notes) to the notebook, hope it helps.

Comment: @ASHu2 The 'subview rendering' of each individual subview by itself is expected and works correctly. It is from the line: `for m in models: display(m)`. The error happens when adding a new view in the *parent* object, using `this.create_child_view(child_model)`.

Comment: Thanks. Could you check `t.get_manager_state()` if most of the outputs are `none`?

Comment: @ASHu2 [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sngiznajlls2z29/get_manager_state_output.js)

Comment: yeah, same with me, therefore I logged the console for `render function`, but it does not print, does not that mean that the function does not execute ?

Comment: @ASHu2 if you mean the `SubView.render`, correct- it does not execute. `TestView.render` does execute. Error occurs at the line: `return this.create_child_view(child_model)`.

Comment: @ASHu2 clarification: the `SubView.initialize` does not execute, either. the problem is the `SubView` object never gets created. something is failing in the `create_child_view` method. I've stared at the code and tried to figure out how to use the API for days.

Comment: @ASHu2 it's not very helpful, but [here's the link to the `create_child_view` method](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/blob/ee9ce168933e953aeb2878c80dc52add40b5ed59/packages/base/src/widget.ts#L653-L660).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194692/discussion-between-ashu2-and-rick-teachey).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly tell the frontend how to de-serialize widgets, i.e. how to turn the string `"IPY_MODEL_*"` into an actual model.

You do this by explicitly defining a model on the frontend side and setting a custom de-serializer for the `children` attribute. This is the counterpart to the `**widgets.widget_serialization` serializers you added to the `children` traitlet on the Python side.

### Notebook

Here's a modified version of the notebook that renders the children:

https://gist.github.com/pbugnion/63cf43b41ec0eed2d0b7e7426d1c67d2

### Full changes

Kernel side, maintain an explicit reference to the JS model class:

```py
class Test(widgets.DOMWidget):
    _model_name = Unicode('TestModel').tag(sync=True)  # reference to JS model class
    _model_module = Unicode('test').tag(sync=True)  # reference to JS model module

    # all the rest is unchanged
    _view_name = Unicode('TestView').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module = Unicode('test').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module_version = Unicode('0.1.0').tag(sync=True)
    children = List(Instance(widgets.Widget)).tag(sync=True, **widgets.widget_serialization)

    def __init__(self, subs):
        super().__init__()
        self.children = subs
```

Then, on the JS side,

1. Import underscore so we can extend objects:

```py
require.undef('test');

define('test', ["@jupyter-widgets/base", "underscore"], function(widgets, _) {
```

2. Define your model module:

```js
    var TestModel = widgets.DOMWidgetModel.extend({}, {
        serializers: _.extend({
            children: { deserialize: widgets.unpack_models }
        }, widgets.WidgetModel.serializers)
    })
```

This tells the widget manager to use the `widgets.unpack_models` function when deserializing the `children` attribute. We might be able to use `Object.assign` instead of underscore here, which would remove the underscore dependency.

3. Export your model:

```js
    return {
        SubView : SubView,
        TestView : TestView,
        TestModel : TestModel
    };
```

### Examples in the wild

I could find a pattern that matches this in the IPyleaflet code base [here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/blob/master/js/src/layers/Layer.js). Look specially in the `LeafletLayerModel` class.

For an example that uses a more modern (babelified) syntax, my `gmaps` package uses widget deserialization [here](https://github.com/pbugnion/gmaps/blob/master/js/src/Map.js#L227).

Comment: This sounds like it might be the correct answer but I tried this exact fix yesterday but I believe I could not get it to work-- I'll find the notebook and post a link, maybe I was doing something incorrectly.

Comment: Ah ha! It works! I was missing the first empty Object argument to widgets.DOMWidgetModel.extend(). I'd like to ask some questions at the GitHub gist if you don't mind.

Comment: I answered your questions directly on the [gist](https://gist.github.com/pbugnion/63cf43b41ec0eed2d0b7e7426d1c67d2).